# Creating a WAP interface for a web application

Tags: spring-mvc, wap, wml

We need to build a WAP interface for our web application, something like the m.domain.com, i.e wap.domain.com. i am a web developer and i need a quick and dirty tutorial or guide that would get me started immediately. My searches haven't produced much, i mean i have found a few tutorials but none of them was much helpful. Can someone please point me to the right direction? what i am essentially trying to do is integrate it into the same application, which is a Spring mvc web app, and use the same domain objects to send the data to the WML pages. i am not even sure if that is entirely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer's Home may help you. Its link is : http://www.developershome.com/wap/wml/wmlIntro.asp

I also had to make a WAP application these days, and this website helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To display your webpage onto a mobile with low res/ or using wap you need to check the version of the browser and os reaching to your device. 
That can be done via js. Once you have identified that the page to be displayed if for low res devices, you can create a web header that redirects to your subdomain @ m.yourdomain.com. 
In your subdomain you will use different css files and low resolution images destined towards displaying on old browsers like symbian OS .etc. "

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. There is a team at '999Studios' who had made this tool to automate the process of making your WAP based services. You can contact them info@999Studios.com. They gave me a free version of the tool. Worked like a charm.